# xubuntu 15.10 display popup after suspend

Tags: suspend, screen, lock

I have installed xubuntu 15.10 and after I disabled "lock screen when system is going for sleep" under power manager --> security. I get a popup of the display settings when the pc wakes up. If I re-enable it everything is fine, but I do not want it to ask for password on wake up.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution under:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-settings/+bug/1264629

Go to 'Settings Manager->Keyboard->Application Shortcuts' then remove XF86Display shortcut.